# Combining (aggregating) county data

Tags: data-portal, state, county

For research, we are using county-level data for fatal car accidents. However, this data is very sparse for counties with small populations. I would like to know if there is a guideline for merging (aggregating) data of counties with small populations.

In other words, is there any unit of analysis that is finer than states but larger than counties with a considerable population?

Comment: What is the connection of this question to Open Data? You may want to go to the Data Science stackexchange with the question of how to aggregate sparse data.

Comment: This question is better placed on teh Data Science stackexchange

Comment: if this is county produced or census data, its open data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Census has Metropolitan and Micropolitan Statistical Areas
https://www.census.gov/population/metro/
as well as Combined Statistical Areas (CSA):
https://www.census.gov/geo/reference/webatlas/csa.html
and CBSA (Core Based Statistical Areas):
https://www.census.gov/geo/reference/gtc/gtc_cbsa.html